# Disable a Combobox in when we select an element from another combobox

Tags: python, qt, combobox, pyqt4

Using PyQt4, I want to hide/disable a combobox when we select option 3 from another combobox.

I know that we can use `QComboBox.setEnabled(False)` to hide/disable the combobox but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

I tried to do this in QT Designer using signal slot editor but there is no option to send a signal from combobox when we select any particular element.

This the GUI Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_test_gui(object):
    def setupUi(self, test_gui):
        test_gui.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("test_gui"))
        test_gui.resize(400, 300)
        self.primarybox = QtGui.QComboBox(test_gui)
        self.primarybox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 69, 22))
        self.primarybox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("primarybox"))
        self.primarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.primarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.primarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.primarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.primarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.secondarybox = QtGui.QComboBox(test_gui)
        self.secondarybox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 70, 69, 22))
        self.secondarybox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("secondarybox"))
        self.secondarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.secondarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.secondarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.secondarybox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

        self.retranslateUi(test_gui)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(test_gui)

    def retranslateUi(self, test_gui):
        test_gui.setWindowTitle(_translate("test_gui", "Dialog", None))
        self.primarybox.setItemText(0, _translate("test_gui", "Comb1", None))
        self.primarybox.setItemText(1, _translate("test_gui", "option1", None))
        self.primarybox.setItemText(2, _translate("test_gui", "option2", None))
        self.primarybox.setItemText(3, _translate("test_gui", "option3", None))
        self.primarybox.setItemText(4, _translate("test_gui", "option4", None))
        self.secondarybox.setItemText(0, _translate("test_gui", "comb2", None))
        self.secondarybox.setItemText(1, _translate("test_gui", "element1", None))
        self.secondarybox.setItemText(2, _translate("test_gui", "element2", None))
        self.secondarybox.setItemText(3, _translate("test_gui", "element3", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test_gui = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_test_gui()
    ui.setupUi(test_gui)
    test_gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QComboBox`has a signal `currentIndexChanged`. It is emitted when the user select a new choice in a combobox. The new index is passed with the signal.
You can connect this signal to a function that will disable the second combobox if the new index is 2 (aka option 3)

```
self.comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_change)

def on_change(self, newIndex):
    if newIndex==2:
        self.comboBox2.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works and I appreciate it but I never understood why you down voted my question. Some typing error was there but i feel it was too much to down vote it.